# Highcharts - Tooltip over line between points

Tags: highcharts, hover, tooltip

In *Highcharts* is there an option to show the tooltip between points when hovered over the line?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a tour(http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the help center(http://stackoverflow.com/help). You might also want to read How to Ask(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, showing the tooltip in different locations than the default is possible, however: 1) what have your tried to date that has not worked? 2) do you have an example, whether that's an image or code, that shows what you're trying to accomplish? 3) what is your use case for having a tooltip between points?

Comment: Have you tried using tooltip.positioner? Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/oLe6zkud/1/